# O que significa declarar const {service} em Javascript, NODE.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-service

Ao começar a estudar Node.JS me deparei com o seguinte trecho de código:

> Example with services that shows middleware factory advantages.

```
...

const {service} = options;
router.get('/greet', (req, res, next) => {
        res.end(
                service.createGreeting(req.query.name || 'Stranger')
        );
 });
return router;
```

O que significa essa declaração, por que estas {} no service?

> const {service} = options;

Comment: Leia sobre [Desestruturação de objeto](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Atribuicao_via_desestruturacao#desestrutura%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_objeto)